# CKeditor removes style attribute even though set in allowedContent

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I created a custom image browser/uploader plugin for ckeditor. I'm having some trouble integrating the [advanced content filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf)

Basically what's happening is I have a field on a dialog tab that allows a user to edit the inline style for the image. This is working correctly it seems as the styles get added to the img tag and after saving to the database and when viewing the generated html the image is styled correctly. However when you go to edit the document again CKeditor has stripped out the style attribute.

in plugin.js I am setting the allowedContent property to include the style attribute

```
editor.addCommand( 'sbImageDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'sbImageDialog', 
   {allowedContent: 'img[src][style]', requiredContent: 'img[src]' }
));
```

in the dialog js I am defining a tab called "advanced" that requires the style attribute to be allowed in order to show

```
{
    id: 'advanced',
    label: 'Advanced',
    elements: [
        {
            type: 'text',
            id: 'style',
            label: 'Style',
            requiredContent: 'img[style]',
            setup: function( element ) {
                this.setValue( element.getAttribute('style') );
            },
            commit: function ( element ) {
                var style = this.getValue();
                if ( style )
                    element.setAttribute( 'style', style );
                else if ( !this.insertMode )
                    element.removeAttribute( 'style' );
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

since that tab does show up and the image is styled correctly when viewed it seems like I have it set up correctly.

So why is CKeditor stripping out the style attribute when I return to edit the document? Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer so I'll add it here in case it will help someone else.

Where in plugin.js I had

```
editor.addCommand( 'sbImageDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'sbImageDialog', 
   {allowedContent: 'img[src][style]', requiredContent: 'img[src]' }
));
```

I had to change the `allowedContent` property from `'img[src][style]'` to `'img[src][style]{*}'`

The curly braces indicate what css style properties the element is allowed to have. By putting `*` I am allowing all css style properties.

Comment: Not `'img[src][style]{*}'`, but `'img[src]{*}'`. And if you want to allow multiple attributes, then `'img[src,alt]'`. Read more in the [allowed content rules docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules).